# what is the use of declaration section in app.module in angular

Tags: angular

```
declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AdminLayoutComponent,
        AuthLayoutComponent
    ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Comment: Read https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules#ngmodule-metadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration array is used to tell the app module that they are part of the app module then it lets you access all these components using selector anywhere in a component that is part of the app module.

AdminLayoutComponent -- you can use this component in AppComponent or in another component that is part of the app module

bootstrap - This is the initial component that loads when the app starts.

Note1: if you declare a component in app module then you cannot access that component in another module so if you want to access this component in another module then you also have to declare in that module too.

Note2: If you have B-module and have declared B-component here and also have exported this component in the export array then you can inject B-module in other module and access the B-component

For more info refer the documentation https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules#ngmodule-metadata
[image]

Comment: That info is not right: `if you want to access this component in another module then you also have to declare in that module too` as it will raise the error: `The Component xxxx is declared by more than one NgModule` (tested in angular 11.2.7)

Answer (score 0):

The declaration array is used is declare components, directives and pipes belongs to NgModule in your angular application. Their scope will be inside module only until you export them in **exports array** of NgModule .

Answer (score 0):

At declarations Array you can put all your components directives or pipes, that you should use at any of modules of project. You should put it inside a NgModule. Also you could have an exports array, where you can export all your components inside a module.